# Break D3 Each Loop Without a flag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, each

Consider the following code:

```
circle.each(function (d) {
    //...code
});
```

How can I break the loop? Is there a natural D3 way to break out of an each loop? I mean without a flag as follows:

```
var flag = false;
circle.each(function (d) {
    if (flag) return;
    if (someCondition) flag = true;
    //...code
});
```

I've tried returning false inside the if statement but it did not work (thought that maybe this would work the same as `jquery.each` but I was wrong):

```
circle.each(function (d) {
    if (someCondition) return false; //Not working
    //...code
});
```

Comment: i've edited my question in order to avoid confusions. Code is not relevant. everything is working I just want to know how to properly break the loop if its posible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not. Take a look at the each source code https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/78e0a4bb81a6565bf61e3ef1b898ef8377478766/src/selection/each.js.

You may be able to throw an exception to break the loop, but unless your case is really "exceptional", using an exception is probably more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you can do following

```
var flag = false;
circle.some(function (d) {
    if (flag) return true;
});
```

Comment: :( I don't think this function exists in the latest version of d3 anymore.